# Echo string containing single and double quotes to input value

Tags: php, input, htmlspecialchars

I'm extracting a string from XML and want to insert it as the value of an input text box. And I'm having problems with this string containing both single and double quotes:

`We will have a "New Year's Eve countdown"`

Here is the code I'm using to output this. I've tried using `htmlspecialchars` but it doesn't stop the html code breaking because of the mix of quotes in the string.

`echo "<p>Info <input type='text' name='info' value='".htmlspecialchars($result->info)."' size='20' /></p>";`

How can I fix this so that it correctly displays the value of the string in the text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `ENT_QUOTES` flag to [`htmlspecialchars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars) to get it to convert both double *and* single quotes to their html entity equivalent:

```
echo "<p>Info <input type='text' name='info' value='".htmlspecialchars($result->info, ENT_QUOTES)."' size='20' /></p>";
```

This will produce the following HTML:

```
<p>Info <input type='text' name='info' value='We will have a &quot;New Year&#039;s Eve countdown&quot;' size='20' /></p>
```

Which as you can see from this snippet, displays the desired string in the text input:

```html
<p>Info <input type='text' name='info' value='We will have a &quot;New Year&#039;s Eve countdown&quot;' size='50' /></p>
```